# How do i open in image using PIL if the image if the file is on someone else's pc so i dont know their directories

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Noob question, so when using PIL and Image. Open to add an image to window I add the location of the file on my PC, but how would i go about doing this if I was sending this to another persons PC and I didn't know the location of their files?

Sorry if the question is poorly explained

Comment: You would probably prompt them for the image location as part of your program. Potentially accepting a path as a command line or method parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not specific enough IMO.

However, given as much info as you provided I see 3 simple solutions:

1. Allow the user to specify the path to the image either through a command-line argument or configuration file.
2. Tell others to include the file in specific directory

> image_path = "image_name.jpg"
>
> img = Image.open(image_path)

3. Just put the image into the repository itself or the compressed file, if you don't use one.